# Managing browser history in Dart

Tags: html, dart, single-page-application, browser-history

I'm building a single-page Dart web app that will essentially consist of 1 Dart file (cross-compiled to JS) and 1 HTML file that has several "views" (screens, pages, etc.). in it. Depending on what "view" the user is currently located at, I will hide/enable different DOM elements defined inside this HTML file. This way the user can navigate between views without triggering multiple page loads.

I would still like to use each browser's native history-tracking mechanism, so that the user click can the back- and forward-buttons in the browser, and I'll have a Dart `Historian` object figure out what view to load (again just hiding/enabling DOM elements) depending on what URL the browser has in its history.

I've pretty much figured everything out, with one exception:

Say the user is currently "at" View #3, which has a URL of, say, `http://myapp.example.com/#view3`. Then they click a button that should take them to View #4 at, say, `http://myapp.example.com/#view4`. I need a way, in Dart, to tell the browser to:

1. Set `http://myapp.example.com/#view4` in the browser URL bar
2. Add `http://myapp.example.com/#view4` to the browser's history
3. If not already enabled, enable the browser's back button

I *believe* I can accomplish #1 above like so:

```
window.location.href = "http://myapp.example.com/#view3";
```

...but maybe not. Either way, how can I accomplish this (Dart code communicates with browser's history API)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [route](https://github.com/dart-lang/route) library.

[angular.dart](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart) also has it's own routing mechanism, but it's part of a much larger framework, so unless you plan on using the rest of it, I would recommend the stand-alone route library.

If you want to build your own solution, you can take a look at route's [client.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/route/blob/master/lib/client.dart) for inspiration.

There are two methods of history navigation supported:

1. The page fragment method that you've used. Reassign the window location to the new page fragment: `window.location.assign(newPathWithPageFragment)`. Doing this will automatically add a new item to the browser history (which will then enable the back button).
2. The newer History API, which allows for regular URLs without fragments (e.g. `http://myapp.example.com/view3`. You can use [window.history](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/History.html) to control the history.The History API is only supported by newer browsers so that may be a concern (although given that dart2js also only supports newer browsers, there are probably not too many instances of a browser that dart2js supports that doesn't support the History API).

One issue you will have to handle if you support History API is the initial page load. When a user navigates to `http://myapp.example.com/view3`, the browser expects to find a resource at that location. You will have to setup your server to respond to any page request by serving your Dart application and then navigate to the correct view on the client-side. This issue will apply whether you use route, angular.dart, or build your own solution, since this is a general server-side issue and the above are all client-side libraries.

Comment: Thanks @Pixel Elephant (+1) - but I'm trying to do this with a pure homegrown solution...essentially I'm trying to learn "pure Dart" so that I **really** understand it, so I'd rather not depend on someone else's code to do what I want here...do you know what *part* of the `route` lib I'd be interested in for my question? Or do you know off-hand how I could accomplish objectives 1 - 3? Thanks again!

Comment: I've added some more info about routing. I'd recommend you use the route library if you are actually writing production code. They've already take care of issues such as nested routes, that you will have to manually solve yourself (though I definitely do support really understanding the code involved!).

Comment: As always, thanks again @Pixel Elephant (+1) - it definitely seems like `window.history.pushState` is what I want for my second issue (adding the View #4 to the browser history via History API). **However**, what do I need to pass as `pushState`'s first argument (the `Object data` argument)? Reading the [`History`](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/be/latest/dart_html/History.html#pushState) dart docs doesn't make it obvious what "data" is...can you give or think of an example? Thanks enormously!

Comment: I'm not actually sure, I've never used the data argument. I'd guess it's some extra data about the state that you might want to store (e.g. maybe what checkboxes were selected on the view or something like that), so that you can retrieve it when the user goes back to that state. You can just pass `null` if you don't have any special data to store.